# securing form validation using ajax

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I am working on an application which was developed by some one else. There are few issues where i am not sure if they are good enough.

Registration form

if the user enters a username in registration form an Ajax request is generated something like

```
t=members&f=username&value=enterd-username
```

which tests for uniqueness of username, i.e. it tests if the `members` table's `username` field is unique or not.

Unfortunately I can't change all the registration process. but is there a way to make this safe against `SQLInjections`?

Comment: nothing client side is really ever going to be secure - all the bulletproofing needs to be done at the backend

Answer (score 0):

Use following function to sanitize user input

**MYSQL:**

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
```

**MYSQLI:**

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
```

**NOTE** = `$con` is the database connection object